# wrong output. remove element from list1 if exist in list2

Tags: python, arrays, django, list

The code is to remove elements present in another list.

Wrong Output

Code is written here:

````
s=['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com',]
for e in l:
    if e in s:
        l.remove(e)
print(l)```

Showing wrong output

**output should be =['c@gmail.com','d@gmail.com']**
**but output coming is ['b@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','d@gmail.com']**
````

Comment: What's inside `l`?

Comment: is preserving order of elements relevant?

Answer (score 4):

removing items from a list while you are iterating over with `for` loop  it is not best practice and will lead you to unexpected behavior, you can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [e for e in l if e not in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If preserving order of elements is not relevant this would result in much faster times

```
result = list(set(l) - set(s))
```

Note for solution above with list comprehension from @kederrac if you do just set(s) it would be also faster than withouth it

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['a','b']
l3 = []
for i in l1:
    if i not in l2:
        l3.append(i)

print(l3)
```

output :

```
['c', 'd']
```

check with the length of the list and loop it accordingly.